# Mixed OIDC based SPA Client + OAuth Server Client scenario?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm trying to plan the optimal way to allow for the following development:

Components:

- a SPA Client: which communicates with:
- an API based Server: developed by the same org

Both SPA and Server are in turn Clients of 3rd party APIs, such as:

- AAD Graph API

---

In the above case, is the following correct:

- the SPA signs in to AAD using OIDC Implicit Flow, and is returned two tokens: `token` + `id_token`
- the SPA persists the two tokens in isolated storage.
- the SPA communicates with the back end server's APIs.

  - passing the token as a Bearer Token in the Authorisation header.
  - **Q:** it it correct that in OAuth 2.0 Framework it states that the access token should *not* be shared beyond private clients -- but in OIDC we're taking this liberty because the SPA is considered as just a component of the same system, and that's *moderately* ok as long as we don't expose the client id?
  - **Q:** passes the `id_token` back as well? Or is that better kept on SPA side, as server doesn't need more than `sub` to id of user, which it obtains from the access_token's JWT.
  - **Q:** if it is sent, how?!? if the Authorisation header is already being used for the access token?
  - **Q:** This has flummoxed me: how does the backend server know what scopes the user has? Neither the OAuth 20 Framework, nor the OIDC protocol does not specify that a `scp` property is part of the protocol. And Some OPs (eg: AAD) do not provide an introspect endpoint. There must be more than just accepting that the token is untamperable, no?
  - **Q**: Could the backend server get its hands on the `id_token` (maybe to get the user's email address) if it needed to?

    - **Q**: How? Is that done by doing a /token request, providing the `token` to get an `id_token`, as long as the token is not expired?
- the SPA which needs to connect to OAuth will request a *separate* OAuth access token for the calls to AAD. That too will be cached in isolated storage.
- **Q**: Is it correct that if the WebService is to proxy requests to AAD, on behalf of the SPA's user, the Client has to first ensure -- on the SPA side -- that its first token has been granted additional scopes -- adding the AAD scopes to the scopes it used to get to the API server's scopes.
- **Q**: If the API Webservice is to make calls to AAD on behalf of the service, with no reference to end users (eg: a webjob, or before the enduser has signed in) then the calls would have to use Client Credentials Flow?
  In the above, no cookies would be used between SPA and API server. Is that an optimal approach?

---

The implicit flow means the token will expire...and will not be able to be refreshed, or "remember Me'ed".  Is there ever a case for the SPA to invoke a WebServer page which performs an Authorisation Code Grant Flow, and then returns the Auth Token to the server? That way both halves of the distributed client have the same `token`s?

If so...any examples?! Leads??

---

- **Q**: One question I've always had trouble understanding: in windows, the claims show what scope the user has. How does it use that information to find the right token in the cache? Or is just not relevant -- it uses the audience attribute to find the only cache for that person on that target client, and attaches that?

---

Thank you very (very!*) much for any and all corrections/suggestions to the above.

* In 10 years I've never been as flummoxed by a protocol/Framework as the OIDC/OAuth RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

Answering for AAD, other IdPs can handle things differently.

> Q: it it correct that in OAuth 2.0 Framework it states that the access token should not be shared beyond private clients -- but in OIDC we're taking this liberty because the SPA is considered as just a component of the same system, and that's moderately ok as long as we don't expose the client id?

I'm not sure on the official spec but it is pretty typical to use access tokens to access back-end APIs from an SPA/native client.
The client id is pretty public info, anyone can find it from your authentication redirect URL.

> Q: passes the id_token back as well? Or is that better kept on SPA side, as server doesn't need more than sub to id of user, which it obtains from the access_token's JWT.

Usually no, the id token is meant for your front-end.

> This has flummoxed me: how does the backend server know what scopes the user has? Neither the OAuth 20 Framework, nor the OIDC protocol does not specify that a scp property is part of the protocol. And Some OPs (eg: AAD) do not provide an introspect endpoint. There must be more than just accepting that the token is untamperable, no?

You can implement custom roles in your API with AAD like this: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-2.
Those roles can then be assigned to users.
The access token will then have those roles.
Token validity is checked by validating the signature + audience + expiry time + issuer with AAD.

> Could the backend server get its hands on the id_token (maybe to get the user's email address) if it needed to?

In the case of AAD, no. An id token is only given after user authentication.
With AAD you would call the Microsoft Graph API to get more info on the user.

> Q: Is it correct that if the WebService is to proxy requests to AAD, on behalf of the SPA's user, the Client has to first ensure -- on the SPA side -- that its first token has been granted additional scopes -- adding the AAD scopes to the scopes it used to get to the API server's scopes.

Not sure I follow this one.
The token the client receives is not for AAD/MS Graph.
So it will not contain those scopes.
Your API can exchange the token it receives for a token for MS Graph, containing the granted scopes for that.

> Q: If the API Webservice is to make calls to AAD on behalf of the service, with no reference to end users (eg: a webjob, or before the enduser has signed in) then the calls would have to use Client Credentials Flow? In the above, no cookies would be used between SPA and API server. Is that an optimal approach?

If you want to make calls purely as the service, then client credentials flow is the way to go.

> The implicit flow means the token will expire...and will not be able to be refreshed, or "remember Me'ed". Is there ever a case for the SPA to invoke a WebServer page which performs an Authorisation Code Grant Flow, and then returns the Auth Token to the server? That way both halves of the distributed client have the same tokens?

ADAL.JS/MSAL.JS (the libraries used commonly for SPAs with AAD) use a hidden iframe to get new tokens with `prompt=none`.
It depends on the user having an active session with AAD.

> Q: One question I've always had trouble understanding: in windows, the claims show what scope the user has. How does it use that information to find the right token in the cache? Or is just not relevant -- it uses the audience attribute to find the only cache for that person on that target client, and attaches that?

It uses the audience to know the service the token is meant for.
The subject claim will tell what principal the token was acquired for.
ADAL for example has APIs that allow you to tell it what resource (= audience) you want to call, and as what user (if applicable).
It then finds the right token in its token cache.

---

I hope this answers at least some of your questions :)